# Как узнать какая кодировка у строки?

Tags: php, кодировка

Как узнать какая кодировка у строки? Короче у Апача в конфигурации ЮТФ-8, на всех страницах тоже. Но блин это не работает

```
      strtolower($_POST['name'])
      uc_first($name);

   <?   
$data = explode(" ", trim($_POST["name_firstname"]));
$name =  mb_convert_case($data[0], MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
echo uc_first($name);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

mb_convert_case($_POST['name'], MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");

Comment: а вот так почему не работает?
$name =  ucfirst(trim(mb_convert_case($data[0], MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8")));

Comment: Как вариант кодировка файла не UTF8

Comment: Юникод(UTF-8 без сигнатуры)кодовая страница 65001. Исправил вопрос

Comment: Не знаю что вы там шаманите но 
$data[0] = "АФЫВФЫВФ";
echo $data[0];
$name = ucfirst(trim(mb_convert_case($data[0], MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8")));
echo $name;
обрабатывает у меня спокойно

Comment: короче, это проблема только с русскими буквами

Answer (score 0):

[На хабре есть довольно интересный пост.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/)

Comment: не в этом беда, все выводится нормально, но функции с русским алфавитом не выполняются